# moveit_setup_assistant loading pr2.urdf.xacro from official tutorial fails

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to **load pr2.urdf.xacro with moveit_setup_assistant** following the  [official tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html)

But after the loading bar reached 100%, the console became dark and finally stopped.

Note that moveit_setup_assistant can **work well with other file** like the moveit tutorial in the book, ros by example vol2.

Here was the error result from terminal.

```
 SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [66948]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to e1e4b9ae-b11e-11e6-b242-000c290a3fdb
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [66961]
started core service [/rosout]
process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [66964]
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ INFO] [1479865759.144299071]: Running 'rosrun xacro xacro.py /opt/ros/indigo/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'...
[ INFO] [1479865763.768824299]: Loaded pr2 robot model.
[ INFO] [1479865763.768900516]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1479865763.788140448]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1479865763.788221240]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1479865763.809109524]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1479865763.809186007]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1479865763.952783314]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1479865763.952884243]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1479865764.130981952]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1479865764.131149135]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
[ INFO] [1479865765.214522606]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1479865765.214625559]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 66964, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/shawn/.ros/log/e1e4b9ae-b11e-11e6-b242-000c290a3fdb/moveit_setup_assistant-2.log].
log file: /home/shawn/.ros/log/e1e4b9ae-b11e-11e6-b242-000c290a3fdb/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

**NOTE:**

version indigo
ubuntu 14.04

---

I cannot deal with this problem yet.

I install Ubuntu dual boot alongside with windows10, instead of using Ubuntu under Vmware. It works now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248650/moveit_setup_assistant-loading-pr2.urdf.xacro-from-official-tutorial-fails/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-23**:\

> OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

Are you running this in a Virtual Machine? If yes: the PR2 model is quite resource intensive, and might cause virtual graphics hw/sw to fail, even if other (simpler) models do work.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-23**:
Yes, I run on vmware station.

```
memory 5.6iB
processor intel i7-6600U 2.6GHz, 
graphics Gallium 0.4 on llvmpip(LLVM 3.8, 256 bits), 
OS type 64-bit
```

So, it there method to deal with it?    /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install Ubuntu dual system alongside with windows, it works now. VM kills....

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-29**:
Good to hear you got it to work.

RViz with complex scenes in VM just doesn't seem to work too well.